# Can Perl 6 sort or compare based on collations?

Tags: collation, raku

The [`cmp` operator](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#infix_cmp) works on code numbers, or at least that's what I think it does because the docs aren't explicit on that and don't mention any localization stuff.

Can I make it sort by other collations? I know I tell [sort](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/sort) how to compare, but I figure it must be in there already (somewhere).

Answer (score 6):

[Collation is available as an experimental feature](https://docs.perl6.org/language/experimental.html#Collation):

```
my @list = <a ö ä Ä o ø>;
say @list.sort;                     # (a o Ä ä ö ø)

use experimental :collation;
say @list.collate;                  # (a ä Ä o ö ø)
$*COLLATION.set(:tertiary(False));
say @list.collate;                  # (a Ä ä o ö ø)
```

Please give feedback on this feature to help it move out of the "experimental" state and be included in v6.d.

Comment: I'm only interested in this feature if I can choose the particular location and not the part of the collation it uses.