# Sorting with modified alphabet in Perl 6

Tags: raku

I have to sort lists of strings using differently 'modified' alphabets.

E.g. between letters 's' and 't' there are two additional letters ('s' with diacritics), so that this part of alphabet becomes: `'... q r s ṣ š t u ...'`.
By default, `sort` will put first words beginning with letters without diacritics and only after them — words beginning with ṣ and š:

```perl6
> my @words = <talk štraw šhabby ṣtraw swamp>
[talk štraw šhabby ṣtraw swamp]
> @words.sort
(swamp talk šhabby štraw ṣtraw)
```

I've made the following program to implement the rules of the 'modified' alphabet, in which I substitute `'ṣ'` and `'š'` with a concatenation of 's' and some of the last Unicode characters (hoping that these characters will never occur in my real data, at least not after `'s'`  ).

```perl6
my $end = 0x10FFFF;
my @last = map * + $end, -10..0;
my @chr_last = @last».chr; # 11 last 
                           # Unicode characters
my Str sub diacr( $word ) {
  my $temp = $word;
  $temp ~~ s:g/ṣ/s@chr_last[0]/;
  $temp ~~ s:g/š/s@chr_last[1]/;
  return $temp;
}

my @words = <talk štraw šhabby ṣtraw swamp>;
say @words;
say @words.sort(&diacr);
          # (swamp ṣtraw šhabby štraw talk)
```

It works and hopefully gives correct results, but I feel that there should be a more elegant and straightforward way to do the same thing.

**UPD:** [Here's a discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44937854/7730888) about [experimental features](https://docs.perl6.org/language/experimental.html#Collation) like `collate` and `coll`, but I don't see how to use them to solve my particular problem.

Comment: Sounds to me like you are reimplementing [collate](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/collate), [coll](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/coll), or [unicmp](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/unicmp). [The current docs are here](https://docs.perl6.org/language/experimental#index-entry-collate-collate)

Comment: @BradGilbert Do I understand correctly that it is not implemented yet? Or there is some way to modify `$*COLLATION` variable and use something like `sort(coll)`?

Comment: The current default implementation of `.collate` doesn't fit me, since e.g. it puts 'š' before 'ṣ' and I need to put it after it: `> say <š ṣ s t r>.collate  # produces
(r s š ṣ t)`

Comment: As I see from the current value of the `$*COLLATION` variable, it only contains some values for `Country`, `Language`, as well as `primary` (Language)... `quaternary`. So, I suppose, that even if I somehow change the `$*COLLATION` variable, it won't be possible to implement my modified 'alphabet', which don't correspond to any actual language. `collation-level => 85, Country => International, Language => None, primary => 1, secondary => 1, tertiary => 1, quaternary => 1`

Comment: [Unicode::Collate](https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/73y7di/201740_unicode_granted/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a simple way either. But anyway, here is another attempt in the same direction as you already did:

```
sub transform($char) {
    state @order = [<s ṣ š>, <a â>];
    my $non_mark_char = $char.samemark("a");
    for @order -> $subset {
        my $pos = $subset.grep($char, :k);
        die "Unexpected subset $subset" if $pos.elems > 1;
        if $pos.elems == 1 {
            $pos = $pos[0] + ord("0");
            return $non_mark_char ~ chr($pos);
        }
    }
    return $char;
}

my Str sub diacr($word) {
    return $word.comb.map({ transform($_) }).join('');
}

my @words = <tâlk talk štraw šhabby ṣtraw swamp>;
say @words.sort(&diacr);
```

**Output**:

```
(swamp ṣtraw šhabby štraw talk tâlk)
```

Comment: As with my method, I see here a potential (but rather unrealistic) problem: if e.g. there are more 20–30 variants of `s` with diacritics (that should go after pure `s`), we will have to represent them as `s` concatenated with real characters, and this may interfere with 'real' `s` followed by these characters.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky  *"I see here a potential (but rather unrealistic) problem [...] this may interfere with 'real' s followed by these characters"* : It should not be a problem since also the real `s` is substituted by `s` and an order code? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Mea culpa! My understanding was wrong, so I deleted my first comment. Your solution is very clear and, I suppose, will be much more effective than what I've implemented yesterday. The only thing I can't understand is why you use `$pos[0]` instead of `$pos`.

Comment: But if a `$subset` consists of more than 10 characters, it won't work. If we compare `sbc` and `ṣ̌̄̄bc`, `<s1bc s12bc>.sort` produces `(s12bc s1bc)`

Comment: @EugeneBarsky Good point, but I think the next character after 9 will be a colon `:` if we follow the ASCII table, and not the two characters `10`, am I right?

Comment: I've implemented your method into my program, and with my real data it works 7 times faster than my current version!

Comment: @EugeneBarsky *"The only thing I can't understand is why you use `$pos[0]` instead of `$pos`"* : Because `grep(..., :k)` returns a sequence. But you are right! A sequence of exactly one element behaves like a scalar (I tested it with some simple cases), so there is really no need for the indexing, `$pos[0]` is the same as `$pos` if `$pos.elems == 1`.